# Faster (vectorised?) version of pandas get_loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have two dataframes: one with sparse dates and associated values on those dates, the other with much more dates. I'd like to find the value of a date in dataframe 2 by finding the value on the closest date in dataframe 1. E.g., if dataframe 1 looks like

```
  |date       |value |
___________________
0 | 1/01/2021 |   0.4|
1 | 2/01/2021 |   0.2|
```

and dataframe 2 like:

```
  |date       |other cols|
______________________
0 | 1/05/2021 | ...     |
...
```

then after the mapping operation dataframe 2 would look like

```
  |date       |mapped value|other cols|
______________________________________
0 | 1/05/2021 |   0.4      | ...     |
...
```

I've figured out how to do this using get_loc with the `'nearest'` method

```py
def val_map(row):
    """Find value for date in df2 closest to date in df1"""
    return df1.rate.iloc[df1.index.get_loc(row.date, method='nearest')]
    
df2['mapped_value'] = df2.apply(val_map, axis=1) # first, get nearest avg IR
```

However... this is extremely slow when scaled to a dataframe with >1M rows. What are my options to do this vectorially?

Comment: Most likely the bottleneck is not the `get_loc` itself, is the  fact you are using `apply`. But anyway, it seems that you are looking  for [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html).

Answer (score 0):

Following HarryPlotter's advice, I used `merge_asof`

```py
df = pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('ROW_CREATED_DATE'), df1, left_on='date_df2', right_on='date_df1', direction="nearest") # creates new column 'value'
```

Very fast!